# Elasticsearch set default field analyzer for index

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering if it is possible to modify the behviour of ES when dynamically mapping a field. In my case I don't want ES to map anything. Most of the fields I have are considered `text` by ES when the field occurs for the first time.

The correct mapping though for our application is 99% always `keyword` since we don't want the tokenizer to run on it. Can we modify the behaviour for new fields to be always mapped as `keyword` (unless defined otherwise in the index mapping of course)

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) to solve your issue. Moreover, Elasticsearch guide has [snippet](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#_structured_search) which is suitable for your case.

Comment: Awesome thank you! That was a feature of ES I didn't stumble upon yet.